# How to get single value from jinja2 template?

Tags: json, parsing, jinja2

I got next template

```
        "value": [
            1559913851.923, 
            "5"
        ]
```

How to get "5" value? I've tried select first/last value through [0] and [1], but it show  both numbers [0], or empty repsonse [1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it was no so hard as i think:

```
value [0][1]
```